# Python class can't find attribute

Tags: python, class, function

Basically, I want to run the connect function but I keep getting the CMD error message 'class StraussBot has no attribute 'connectSock' but I can obviously see it does. I've tried searching on here and I can't find any resolutions to this issue. SO it will be greatly appreciated if you could help me find why this isn't finding the 'connectSock' function.

Code:

```
import socket
    from config import HOST, PORT, CHANNEL

# User Info
USER = "straussbot" # The bots username
PASS = "oauth:sj175lp884ji5c9las089sm9vvaklf" # The auth code

class StraussBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Ssock = socket.socket()

    def connectSock(self):
        self.Ssock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        self.Ssock.send(str("Pass " + PASS + "\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))
        self.Ssock.send(str("NICK " + USER + "\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))
        self.Ssock.send(str("JOIN " + CHANNEL + "\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting the bot..."
    while True:
        straussbot = StraussBot
        try:
            straussbot.connectSock()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Comment: `straussbot = StraussBot()`, you're missing parens.

Comment: In your main block, you're setting `straussbot` to the _class_ StraussBot, not an _instance_ of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused by the error here. You get an `AttributeError` for `self.Ssock` because you do not have an instance.

You only created a reference to the class here:

```
straussbot = StraussBot
```

You need to *call* the class to produce an instance:

```
straussbot = StraussBot()
```

You are also mixing tabs and spaces:

[image: tabs in source]

Note how lines 5 through 9 have *lines* in the indentation, but the rest have dots? Those are tabs, and Python sees those as *8 spaces*. So your `connectSock` method is indented *inside* of `__init__` and not seen as a method on `StrausBot`.

You'll have to stick to either *just tabs* or *just spaces*. Python's styleguide strongly recommends you use spaces only.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to instantiate an object of your class `StraussBot`.

```
straussbot = StraussBot
```

just assigns the name `straussbot` to refer to the class `StraussBot`. Change that line to

```
straussbot = StraussBot()
```

to actually create an instance of your class. You can then call the `connectSock` method on that instance as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. You might think your `StraussBot` class has a `connectSock` method, but you actually put the definition of `connectSock` nested inside the `__init__` method.

Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to see the problem. There's probably a "convert tabs to spaces" option you can use to autofix it. Running Python with the `-tt` option will make Python notify you when something like this happens.

Also, you'll need to actually create an instance of `StraussBot`, rather than just setting `straussbot` to the class itself: `straussbot = StraussBot()`.