# Python class can't find member

Tags: python, pandas, function, class, dataframe

I tried to put some basic preprocessing operations of a pandas dataframe into a seperate class:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

class MyClass:
    def _init_(self):
        pass

    @jit

    def preprocess_dataframe(self, path):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False, delimiter=' ' , names=['Time', 'Downloads', 'ServerID', 'Server', 'Date'], usecols=['Time', 'Downloads', 'Server', 'Date'])

        print(self.df.head(5))
        self.df['Date'] = self.df['Date'].astype(str)
        self.df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Time'] +' '+ self.df['Date'], format='%H:%M:%S %Y%m%d')
        self.df[['Server_alone', 'Instance']] = self.df['Server'].str.split('-' ,expand=True)

        self.df.drop(columns=['Time'], inplace=True)

        self.df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

        self.df.set_index(self.df['Date'])

        return self.df
```

When I call this function in my main script (see below) I receive the error:

`AttributeError: module 'MyClass' has no attribute 'preprocess_dataframe'`

This is the relevant part of my main script:

```
import MyClass as mc

path = 'Data.txt'

df = mc.preprocess_dataframe(path)

>>>AttributeError: module 'MyClass' has no attribute 'preprocess_dataframe'
```

I looked up several other questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931530/python-class-cant-find-attribute). However, nothing solved my issue despite I think that the fix is quite easy. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you should be doing `obj = mc.MyClass()`

Comment: you need an instance of the class to call its method or make the method static

Comment: @Sparky05 How do I make it static?

Comment: Add an @staticmethod see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python

Comment: I receive the error ```'module' object is not callable``` @SamMason

Comment: `mc.MyClass().preprocess_dataframe(path)`?

Comment: It perfectly works now. I named MyClass differently in my code. It was kind of an example code right here. Failed to replace everything properly on copy paste. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the method static

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

class MyClass:
    @jit
    @staticmethod
    def preprocess_dataframe(path):
        df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False, delimiter=' ' , names=['Time', 'Downloads', 'ServerID', 'Server', 'Date'], usecols=['Time', 'Downloads', 'Server', 'Date'])

        print(self.df.head(5))
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
        df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'] +' '+ df['Date'], format='%H:%M:%S %Y%m%d')
        df[['Server_alone', 'Instance']] = df['Server'].str.split('-' ,expand=True)

        df.drop(columns=['Time'], inplace=True)

        sdf['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

        df.set_index(df['Date'])

        return df
```

and call it the following way

```
from filename import MyClass

path = 'Data.txt'

df = MyClass.preprocess_dataframe(path)
```

Comment: That answer might be pretty close. However, I receive this error now: ```TypeError: preprocess_dataframe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'``` Maybe it has to do something with having ```(self, path``` as arguments before?

Comment: You must remove the self argument. I have changed the method, too. (Removing all references to self)

Comment: It perfectly works now. I named MyClass differently in my code. It was kind of an example code right here. Failed to replace everything properly on copy paste. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't want to bundle multiple function inside this class, you don't need the class and could simply define and call the function

Comment: As I have multiple other functions defined in my class, I will keep it in this structure. But thank you for this input, which might ge relevant for other users having the same question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't created an instance of the `MyClass`.
You could rectify it by:

```
df = mc().preprocess_dataframe(path)
```

Also change the import statement as well to : `from filename import MyClass as mc`

You could also make `preprocess_dataframe` a staticmethod as mentioned in comments.

Comment: I receive the error ```'module' object is not callable```

Comment: I expected this error. You will have change the import statement as well to : ` from MyClassfilename import MyClass  as mc`

Comment: I think we are close, now I get this error while calling the function ```TypeError: preprocess_dataframe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'```. It must be connected to the method defintion. Do I have to provide something for self as well?

Comment: Did you add mc().preprocess_dataframe(path) as suggested in the answer? Emphasis on `mc()`

Comment: Yes I included it

Comment: That's strange. It seems to run fine here.

Comment: It perfectly works now. I named MyClass differently in my code. It was kind of an example code right here. Failed to replace everything properly on copy paste. Thanks a lot!